# Swapcase Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am definitely stuck on this one and could use your help. What do you think?

```
var swapcase = function(str) {
    var string = str.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) <= 'a' && str.charAt(i) >= 'z') {
            str.charAt(i).toUppercase();
        } else if (str.charAt(i) <= 'A' && str.charAt(i) >= 'Z') {
            str.charAt(i).toLowercase();
        }
    }
    str = letters.join("");
    console.log(str);
    var text = "Life is 10% what happens to you, and 90% of how you REACT to it";
    swapCase(text);
};
```

Comment: But what are you trying to **do**?

Comment: Your operators are backwards.  Also, I think an easier test would be `if(str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i).toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few errors:

1. JavaScript is case-sensitive: is the function called `swapcase` or `swapCase`?
2. `string` isn't a great variable name, especially because you refer to it by a *different name* (`letters`) at the end of the function.
3. Your comparison operators are inverted. Try `>= 'a'`, `<= 'z'`, etc.
4. JavaScript is case-sensitive: you should be calling `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`.
5. You're never calling `swapCase` aside from *inside the function itself*.

The fixed version:

```
var swapCase = function(str) {
    var letters = str.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
            letters[i] = str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
        } else if (str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
            letters[i] = str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    str = letters.join("");
    console.log(str);
    return str;
};

var text = "Life is 10% what happens to you, and 90% of how you REACT to it";
swapCase(text);
```

An easier way to test the case of a character would be:

```
if (str.charAt(i).toLowerCase() === str.charAt(i)) {
    // Character is lower case or not a letter
} else {
    // Character is upper case
}
```

Comment: hahah! Newbie right here definitely! I guess Javascript isn't that flexible. Thank you again and I'll keep those in mind!

Comment: Hey, @MonaMarieCook, no problem! You know, if you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) my answer by clicking the check-mark, this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer (me) and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Happy coding!